# Can't regexp with cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get value from a cell with a type "Time".

In the sheets it's look like just: "*15:40*" (filled manually)

If I use `getValue()` from this cell, and `setValue` to another cell it will be no problem.

But when i'm trying to manage some parsing with regexp i'm getting an error like:

> TypeError: Can't find a function *match* in object "Sun Dec 31 1899 05:22:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)."

Here is the code itself, it's simple:

```
...
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
cellpart = cell.match(..:..);
...
```

Debug says that type im getting not a "String", but "Data" and its value is in the double quotemarks in the errormessage above.
How can i get a string value from the cell? Looks like simple, but i spent all night trying to get whats wrong. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: The most problem i realize now is not tostring conversion, but the data in the value. In the cell i fill only time, and i can see there is a current date also.
But with the getValue() i get totally another time and date. 1899 year etc?

Answer (score 0):

To make your data into a string you can use `.toString()`

```
cell.toString().match(..:..)
```

Note that `cell` is a `Date` object. That's why it doesn't support [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), but you can make it into a string, which will make it the string value `"Sun Dec 31 1899 05:22:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)."`.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that value "Sun Dec 31 1899 05:22:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)." - isn't my value from the cell.
When i'm filling the cell it contains current date and time. And from where cames that one line - i can not understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this problem when creating a mail merge from sheets. I have not had the need to match/ search through these values but the first step in this process is to get the data into a format that you want. After that you can rewrite it back to the cells or process from there.

Below is my method to transfer the date format, then write the values into an array in the format I need. This effectively removed all of the extra garbage date information. Once I had a clean dates, I was able to manipulate that data without a problem.

```
var rawSubmitDate = sheet.getRange((i+2), 1, 1, 1).getValue();
var submitDate = Utilities.formatDate(rawSubmitDate, "PST", "MM/dd/yy");
```

This first portion was used with a loop of the rows with data. You can see I use `.formatDate()` to set the long data form into what I want. You can find more information on how to format the way you need in the GAS reference as well as online on the syntax of date formats.

```
var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
var dataRow = sheet.getRange((i+2), 1, 1, (lastColumn - 2));
var dataArray = dataRow.getValues();
              dataArray[0][2] = whenA;
              dataArray[0][25] = whenB
              dataArray[0][37] = whenC;
              dataArray[0][40] = whenD;
              dataArray[0][43] = whenE;
              dataArray[0][46] = whenF;
```

In this section I create an array of all of my values and write my cleaned dates into that array. The `[]` values are defined by their column index in my row. For instance, the 26th row contained a date that needed to be reformatted (whenB). These dates were things like DOB, time of incident, etc.

I have not written code to place these values back into the sheet because I use `QUERY()` functions to populate the sheet I pull from. Writing values into the cells involved in a `QUERY()` will throw an error. The process however would require a nested loop. The outer loop cycles through rows and the inner loop cycles through the column cells in the row writing each data array value. Outer loop index would be defined by the number of rows you have; Inner loop index would be defined by the number of columns you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getDisplayValue( instead of getValue(.  This will return the cell value as it appears rather than the underlying Date value.

This is the best way I have found to extract a Duration (inserted from a Google Form) without all the gobbledygook inherent in a Date value.